# 汉语里的这种看似而并非纯属口语、平时不跟他字搭配成词的字有特别的名字吗？

Tags: meaning, characters, word, sentence-structure, linguistics

据我所观察，以下字均符合这两个条件：一、看似而并非纯属口语（词典作根据），二、平时不跟他字搭配成词。进一步说，在这些字中，很多平时会被其他频率较高的字或词所代替。

且看：

字：蒙（哄骗）

例句：你别蒙我。

字：蒙（胡乱猜测；碰运气）

例句：这球踢进门，全是蒙上的。

字：蒙（糊涂；不清楚）

例句：一上台就蒙了，不知道该说什么好。

字：蒙（昏迷）

例句：被人打蒙了

字：磨（消耗(时间); 拖延）

例句：一上午就这么磨过去了。

字：磨（纠缠不放）

例句：磨了半天他也不答应。

字：磨（掉转方向）

例句：她一磨身走了。

字：掖（塞；塞进衣袋或缝隙等）

例句：书包掖满了书。

字：掖（藏）

例句：把钱掖好。

字：唧（喷射(液体)）

例句：唧他一身水。

字：蹚（从浅水里走过去）

例句：蹚着水过河。

字：蹚（从草地里或没有路的地方走过去）

例句：在草原上蹚出一条路来

字：噎（因痛苦､激动或顶风而喘不上气来）

例句：哭得他不住地噎气。

字：噎（用话顶撞别人, 使人受窘而说不出话来）

例句：他说话真噎人。

我为什么觉得这些字都较特殊呢？原因难道可以简单地归结为我的汉语水平不高吗？还是这些字和与以上句子类似的话都比我想象的还常见？

编辑：加了一个例子字

Comment: 我并不认为这类字词有专门的分类。这些例子中有些用法，比如“蹚（从草地里或没有路的地方走过去）”，我甚至没听说过——可能本来就是一下地区性用法，由于现在通信发达了，就流传开了。如果您是语言学习者的话建议不要过分关注这些用法，知道是什么意思即可。

Comment: 這些都是不常用的冷門字. 例句中有些是地方口語, 有些是正規用語.

Comment: 不明白你的问题到底是什么。不过如果你觉得这些字词比较陌生，可能是因为方言因素，有些词在某些地区比较常用，另一些地区没那么常用。

Comment: 比如，“把钱掖好”里的“掖”，固然有“好”修饰着“掖”，这里的“掖”不过是单独的一个字。进一步说，这个“掖”在一般情况下就不会使用，一般人就会使用其他的字或词，来表达同样的意思——对吗？跟“把钱藏好”与“把钱保藏好”相比，“把钱掖好”的说法不常用——对吗？我就是说这个“掖”和之类的字呢。顺便问一下，“把钱掖好”应该在哪些地方较常用呢？

Comment: 更多例子：磨了半天-->纠缠了半天，掖满了书 --> 塞满了书，磨了一个上午 --> 浪费了一个上午

Answer (score 1):

蒙：受迷惑（的人）。“蒙者，微昧闇弱之名。”

- 例句：你别蒙我。

  替换为：使迷惑，属于常见的使动用法。即：“你别使我迷惑”
- 例句：这球踢进门，全是蒙上的。

  替换为：在迷惑的状态下，往往带有侥幸的语气。即：“这球踢进门，全是在迷惑的状态下完成的”
- 例句：一上台就蒙了，不知道该说什么好。

  本意，作为状态的转移。即：“（主语）一上台，（主语）就变得很迷惑，不知道该说什么好。”
- 例句：被人打蒙了。

  本意，用在动词后修饰动词导致的结果，以及主语的状态。即：“（主语）被人打了，导致现在（主语）很迷惑”

---

磨：核心含义为摩擦，来自于碾压谷物的石制农具。“以磨碎物亦曰磨。”

- 例句：一上午就这么磨过去了。

  摩擦后事物直观上会减少，因此引申为消耗。此处消耗的对象是时间。
- 例句：磨了半天他也不答应。

  同上引申为消耗。此处消耗的对象是客体（他）的耐心、精力。
- 例句：她一磨身走了。

  此处的磨应当读去声，即四声。当“磨”读四声时，具有最原始的含义：使用石制农具以人力或畜力旋转来达成碾碎谷物去除外壳或获得粉质粮食产品的劳动行为。因此慢慢引申为这种用于加工粮食的工具、加工粮食的生产行为，以及此例中用到的较为不常见的：旋转。且此处的旋转往往仅用于具有类似于操作磨盘时人身体的回转现象，因交通工具的出现也可用于描述车辆，如：比如这个胡同太窄，～不过车来。

---

掖：把东西塞在衣袋或夹缝里。

- 例句：书包掖满了书。
- 例句：把钱掖好。

上面这两个掖都是同义，“藏”的含义隐藏于主体对客体（钱）的态度上，不影响原意。

比较难辨析的是另一个含义。

掖：用手扶着别人的胳膊/扶持别人/旁边。作此含义时读去声，即四声。

这就涉及到通假字，掖通（同）腋，指人的腋下，即大臂和躯干之间。由于搀扶人时往往扶持人的大臂，因此以掖做搀扶；由于人有两个腋下分布于躯干两侧，古代的城墙中，两侧的偏门称为腋门，故也有旁边的含义；由于腋下能够夹持物体，如书本或雨伞等等，就出现了把东西塞在衣袋或夹缝里的含义。

---

下面的很浅显了，都是很常见的语法现象罢了，就不再细谈：

唧

- 例句：唧他一身水。

  认作拟声词即可

蹚：踩，踏。“跌踼，行不正也。”

- 例句：蹚着水过河。

  引申为探路。
- 例句：在草原上蹚出一条路来。

  同上。

噎：食物堵住喉咙。“塞喉曰噎。”不只是食物引起的喉咙堵塞被称为噎，其他原因也可以。

- 例句：哭得他不住地噎气。

  因为情感波动导致的喘不上气。
- 例句：他说话真噎人。

  使动用法。令人喉咙被堵住，即说不上话来。说不上话不是因为物理上喉咙被堵住，而是被他说的话所激怒，被他为人的无耻所惊诧，导致无法用语言来表达自己的愤怒。

---

这些词语在现代汉语中做口语表达居多，都无不是具有鲜明的语法特色和一定的语言演化的，因此会感到奇怪十分正常。

相比之下，我不认为这些单字应该和上面的回答中提到的“弄”相提并论。“弄”作为现代汉语尤其是口语中的万能动词，其地位和量词中的“个”相当，论泛用性约等于古汉语中的“为”，可以大致对应到英语中的do、have、make或是play。因此将“弄”和这些比较不直观的语言现象相比，是不太公平的。

至于你提到的单字，在古汉语中作为单音节词语，演化到现代汉语的过程中还是有迹可循的，因此只要了解这些词语的本身原始含义，再加上日常的使用就能掌握。不像一些汉字的含义已经和其偏旁部首关系相差甚远，个中变化早已无从追溯，面对那种单字就只能承认汉字是历史悠久的象形文字了。

Answer (score 0):

你好，我个人感觉是没有的

有很多词都是在表意不清晰，或者很难想到动词的时候使用

例句：
你把那些剩饭弄弄又可以凑合一顿。

弄就可以当作烹饪的意思

这些词语书面用法比较少，更多的还是口语。

又如你提的蒙

在南方地区很少有这个词汇，蒙进去的球，南方地区（至少广东地区）多用的是：使进去的球

个人感觉这类型的词语还是方言，地方用法中使用较多，并无专门分类